# Gradle & SpringBoot: dependency from parent project causing problems in some child project, but not in all childs

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, spring-ws, spring-boot-actuator

I have a set of java projects. I have a parent build.gradle in a parent project, and a build.gradle for each subproject. This is how the structure looks like:

```
./my-projects
├── project1
│    ├── build.gradle
├── project2
│    ├── build.gradle
├── build.gradle ---> (parent build file)
├── gradle.properties
├── settings.gradle
├── springboot.gradle ---> (common stuff for all sub projects)
├── subprojects.gradle ---> (common stuff for all sub projects)
```

In the parent build.gradle, I have this:

```
apply from: 'springboot.gradle'
apply from: 'subprojects.gradle'
```

In subprojects.gradle, I have declared this dependency in my dependencies:

```
subprojects {
    dependencies { 
        compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services"
    }
}
```

Project1 and Project2 are kind of the same nature. Both are Spring Boot applications. Both uses @RestController annotation to expose a set of REST services. The problem comes down to this: while project1 works perfectly as a REST service, project2 does not. For some reason, project2 acts as a SOAP service. I have services in project2 like GET /project2/my/service which expects an XML as input, and Spring keeps expecting a SOAP Envelop. This is the error:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [messageDispatcherServlet] in context with path [/project2] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapMessageCreationException: Could not create message from InputStream: Unable to create envelope from given source: ; nested exception is com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Unable to create envelope from given source: ] with root cause
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Unable to create envelope from given source because the root element is not named "Envelope"
```

If I remove **compile org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services** from my subprojects.gradle, project2 works perfectly. I have read some docs saying that in order to have a SOAP service you need to include **spring-boot-starter-web-services** dependency. Here:

```
https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/
```

I know I can fix this by removing **spring-boot-starter-web-services**, but I can't just remove it, and this is why: I used project1 and project2 to describe my problem, but reality is that I have checked out a project with 15 applications, and I'm trying to add a 16th app. The **spring-boot-starter-web-services** dependency has been there for a long time and I can't remove it just to make work my new 16th project.

I need to understand why **spring-boot-starter-web-services** works for all the other 15 REST apps, and doesn't for my new 16th app.

I did this workaround in my 16th app build.gradle, but doesn't help me understanding why things doesn't work as expected.

```
configurations {
    all.collect { configuration ->
        configuration.exclude   group: 'org.springframework.ws', module: 'spring-ws-core'
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your dependency tree? `./gradlew dependencies`

Comment: Sure thing. Here are the dependencies for the app that doesn't work: https://pastebin.com/PWDWeBMb. Here are the dependencies for an app which works fine: https://justpaste.it/6u88c

Comment: Hello! Any update? thanks!

Comment: Not sure if this helps but have you looked at the auto config here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.5.9.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/webservices/WebServicesAutoConfiguration.java

This only works if `@ConditionalOnClass(MessageDispatcherServlet.class)` is available